# QPushButton setIcon not working

Tags: c++, qt

I have just started using Qt and I've been trying to get a single button to display an icon but for some reason I can't get it to work. This is my code

```
QPushButton* button = new QPushButton();
button->setIcon(QIcon("icon.png"));
button->show();
```

I don't know what I'm missing here, the `icon.png` and the .cpp file are both in the same folder.. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: the icon.png must be where the executable file is, not where the cpp is, or much better you could put your icon in a resource file.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to make sure your question gets proper attention.

Comment: There are 3 simple solutions, the first place the complete path of the image, or use a qresource to store the image, or place the image in the same folder of your .app.

Comment: The icon.png is currently in the same folder as .app, still can't get it to show

Comment: Try placing the complete path of your image.

Comment: @eyllanesc Still nothing, could there be something wrong with the framework itself?

Comment: Are you sure it is a valid image? I have seen several post where they wanted to show an image, let's say .png but it was actually .jpg that only changed the extension.

Comment: Yeah the extension is right

Comment: If you share your project and your image in a zip could help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add icon folder to your resources.qrc and try this one:

`setIcon(QIcon(QPixmap(":/icons/yourIcon")));`

It works in my project

Comment: for everybody who heard the resource system for the first time, you can look it up here https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html